# Function 'on change' of javascript not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried viewing a list of products based on categories using js ASP.NET MVC 5. I am new to this, it will simply not act on the select box. this is my code:

My Select block:

```
<select class="SelectCategory" name="SelectCategory">
<option value="0">All</option>
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.categories)
{
    if (ViewBag.SelectedCat == item.Value)
    {
        <option selected="selected" value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
    }
    else
    {
        <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
    }
}
```

Js:

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function () {

        $("#SelectCategory").on("change",
            function() {
                var url = $(this).val();
                if (url) {
                    window.location = "/admin/shop/Products?catId=" + url;
                }

                return false;
            });
});

</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#SelectCategory")` this will look for dom with id, but you have used class and name. You can add id attribute to select

```
<select id='SelectCategory' class="SelectCategory" name="SelectCategory">
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#SelectCategory").on("change",`

That's wrong, as your element doesn't contain an ID element which is what the `#` symbol indicates in your jQuery selector.

If you want to target elements by the name attribute, you should use the following:

`$("[name='SelectCategory']").on("change",`